# ggplot correlation heatmap breaks when rendering HTML rmarkdown in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, heatmap, r-markdown

I am trying to add a correlation heatmap using ggplot to an HTML R markdown report. The sample code below works in my R Studio console but breaks when I knit HTML.

The error is vague and I am not sure what the best approach is to debug.

**HTML knit error message:**

> Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : argument "env" is
>   missing, with no default
>
> Calls:  ... ggplot_build -> scales_add_missing ->
>   find_global -> exists

Does anyone else get the same error when they try to knit the code below?

```
library(reshape2)
library(psych)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
a <- sample(c(0,1),20,rep=T)
b <- sample(50:100,20,rep=T)
df <- cbind(a,b)

corr.out <- corr.test(df, adjust = "none", use="complete")

# the stats heatmap function displays fine in R Markdown
heatmap(corr.out$r)

# this ggplot attempt breaks for some reason
dfm <- melt(corr.out$r)

ggplot(data=dfm, aes(dfm$X1, dfm$X2, fill=dfm$value)) + 
      geom_tile() + 
      xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + ggtitle("Correlation coefficients Heatmap") +
      theme(legend.position="bottom")

# i call "dfm$X1" in aes() because i get the error "Object X1 not found" 
# when i only specify "X1"
```

**R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0**

Comment: It's because you don't have the variables X1 and X2 in your "melted" data.frame.  you have var1 and var 2 instead
type `dfm` at the console to see what you get  and try this code `ggplot(dfm, aes(Var1,Var2, fill = value)) + 
     geom_tile() + 
     xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + ggtitle("Correlation coefficients Heatmap") +
     theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

Comment: yup you're right @PeterDee,  that was quick typing :-) and I overlooked that. edited it now